# Python gspread login error 10060

Tags: python, sockets, gmail, gspread

I am attempting to log in to my Google account with gspread. However, it just times out with a `Socket Errno 10060`. I have already activated POP and IMAP access on my email.

```
import gspread
print 1
gc = gspread.Client(auth=('***@gmail.com', '*****'))
print 2
gc.login()
print 2
sht = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XEThXRqWc_Vs4j_6oIuSPXoybj7aUp4h3g1bqPnBzRM/edit#gid=0')
print 3
val = sht.acell('B1').value
```

My error http://tinypic.com/r/ws0ndh/8

Thank guys!

Comment: You don't need POP or IMAP access for gspread to work. What I can see here is you don't have a connection to Google Spreadsheet API server. Do you have a proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

`Socket Errno 10060` means the host isn't responding at all to you. Are you able to access the spreadsheet with your browser? This may be a network settings issue, you may be blocked (I've seen some reports of this online, they may block you if you've been making lots of requests), etc. It's hard to tell, as it's not a fault with your code.

Comment: Yes my browser is able to access the sheet.

Comment: Can you access it in IE? urllib will use IE proxy settings if they exist

Comment: Yes I'm able to access it on IE